# PHP SOAP client Tutorial/Recommendation?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to build some integration with a SOAP service based on .NET 2.0. Im using PHP 5 and have never used SOAP. There doesn't appear to be any straight forward tutorials about how to talk to a soap service using PHP.

Does anyone know where to find some good tutorials or docs?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Do you want to make use of the PHP [SOAP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.soapclient.php) which is already built into PHP?

There is one tutorial: [PHP - Soap Client calling .NET Web service](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/04/16/soap-client-calling-net-web-service/)

[Here](http://devzone.zend.com/article/689) is another one, even though it was created for zend developers it should work fine.

Comment: And if so, do you have a good tutorial at hand? And mind that OP is looking for a SOAP *client*, not server.

Comment: ohh, sorry I must have misunderstood the question

Comment: Thanks' for the asnwer, it has really helped, but now I have a different problem :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684772/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object

Answer (score 10):

I am also searching tutorial found few links, I hope this helps you too:

- http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php
- http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lprNYqe7UAM
- http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/adam_delves20060606.php3?print_mode=1
- http://www.interworx.com/support/docs/developer/api
- http://www.herongyang.com/WSDL/PHP-SOAP-Extension-in-PHP-531.html
- http://plutov.by/post/web_service_soap
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/689
- http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Using-SOAP-with-PHP/
- http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP
- http://developer.apple.com/internet/webservices/soapphp.html
- http://phpsoaptoolkit.sourceforge.net/phpsoap/
- http://www.packtpub.com/article/soap-and-php-5
- http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapprogwsdl.html
- http://devzone.zend.com/25/php-soap-extension/