# how to get value from wsdl returned data in PHP?

Tags: wsdl

Below is the data I'm getting from wsdl response... I need to get the separate value for example how to get the firstname from this array...Please anyone help me...

GetReportResponse Object ( [GetReportResult] => MBPeopleSearchRs_Type Object ( [MsgRsHdr] => MsgRsHdr_Type Object ( [RqUID] => {4DB2AD23-228A-465F-938D-BE072CED61C4} [Status] => Status_Type Object ( [StatusCode] => 0 [ServerStatusCode] => [Severity] => Info [StatusDesc] => OK [AdditionalStatus] => ) ) [Subject] => Subject Object ( [RefNum] => [PersonInfo] => PersonInfo_Type Object ( [PersonName] => PersonName_Type Object ( [LastName] => JANARDHANAN [FirstName] => SENTHINBABU [FullName] => [MiddleName] => [TitlePrefix] => [NameSuffix] => [Nickname] => [LegalName] => [MaidenName] => [OfficialTitle] => [Source] => MB [EffDt] => 2013-05-24 ) [ContactInfo] => ContactInfo_Type Object ( [ContactPref] => [PhoneNum] => [ContactName] => [EmailAddr] => [URL] => [PostAddr] => PostAddr_Type Object ( [PreDirection] => [Addr2] => [PostDirection] => N [Addr3] => [StreetType] => AVE [Addr4] => [StreetName] => LEXINGTON [Apt] => APT 4203 [StreetNum] => 4150 [Addr1] => [City] => SAINT PAUL [StateProv] => MN [PostalCode] => 55126-6131 [County] => RAMSEY

Comment: please add more information, language, framework etc.

Comment: I am trying to solve this in PHP..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a framework for this. CXF is a good choice if you write Java.

http://cxf.apache.org/

edit: since you work with php, take a look here: [PHP SOAP client Tutorial/Recommendation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634077/php-soap-client-tutorial-recommendation)