# Consuming SOAP via sending objects from php client to dotnet SOAP server

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, webservices-client

I have been trying to call a webservice that is in dotnet platform from a client prepared in php.

New to the webservice business and trying my best ...... but I have been unable to send objects from php as client to the dotnet webserver. If anyone could suggest a basic idea or point me to any resource of study where one can send php objects using SOAP to a dotnet it'll be a bunch of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to learn a bit more on how to call SOAP web services from PHP. This question seems to provide a good overview on that: [PHP SOAP client Tutorial/Recommendation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634077/php-soap-client-tutorial-recommendation)

Furthermore, give more details on your concrete problems: what are you being unable to do (more details), what have you already developed/tested?

Finally, when working with SOAP web services you do (should!) not need to care about how the web service is implemented. SOAP is a protocol for managing/specifying the communications between a client and a server (with the web service). The actual internal implementation of the web service should never matter, only its "interface" that normally is defined in the WSDL document.

HTH.

Comment: Well thanks for the heads up @emgsilva ........ and I was unable to send complex type data via a webservice which had wsdl generated in dot net. But with much of the searching I was able to sort it out.

Comment: Came across [Consuming complex type webservice with php](http://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/consuming-soap-complextype-webservice-with-php/) and now i do know how to send complex type data ........ if there is another good approach it would be nice. Regards