# How to use Acumatica Web services to connect with website in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, acumatica, wsdl2php

I am trying to connect with Accumatica using web services. I am using the following resource from acumatica forum.

http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/740-api-how-to-create-api-project-and-use-it-with-c-php-java?p=2809#post2809

I tried to follow all steps but, I was unsuccessful mainly because I am using ftp directly to update files on server and the above resource is for project only on windows.

I already tried researching everything about web services and how to use web services with PHP and how to reference wsdl file in PHP. Please let me know, if you need more information regarding this question.

Thanks,
Jas

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WSDL file what you need is a Soap Client:

http://php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php

[PHP SOAP client Tutorial/Recommendation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634077/php-soap-client-tutorial-recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to have your local envirionment for development.
I mean that you need installed php engine to run php scripts, otherwise it's very inconvenient way to upload files through FTP

Article which you mentioned is really useful, also you can find additional info in Acumatica general help.

basically Acumatica provides SOAP interface to manipulate the data, you have to use SOAP from PHP to ensure connection. Bad thing that PHP doesn't support out from the box SOAP and you have to build, let's say own interfaces based on our WSDL schema's or use native php classes + php_soap client

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try the online solution at [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) as it allows you to generate a PHP package based on the WSDL plus you can send requests without writing even one line of code. You can then download the PHP script to send the request on your own server.

Otherwise, you can also use the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) that creates a PHP package (newer version) that eases the comprehension of how to send the requests as each operation matches a PHP method.